Unable to Create Azure Web App: Error Creating Server Farm
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to create an Azure Web App. Every time I initiate the process, it seems to get stuck at a particular stage and throws an error message mentioning "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms" with a status of "Failed". The error message specifically states:
{ "status": "Failed", "error": { "code": "Forbidden", "message": "The subscription 'mysubscriptionId' is not allowed to create or update the serverfarm.", "details": [ { "message": "The subscription 'mysubscriptionId' is not allowed to create or update the serverfarm." }, { "code": "Forbidden" }, {} ] } } 
I have $200 in my account, and I have already confirmed that my subscription has sufficient permissions to create resources.

Try to change another Region.

While Creating Web app Enable the Basic Authentication.

@AsleshaKantamsetti I have tried multiple regions with authentication enabled and disabled, but I'm still encountering the same issue

Are you using Free trial Subscription?

@AsleshaKantamsetti Yes, but I have upgraded my subscription to pay as you go

Are you able to deploy Azure app after upgradation with out any error?

No, I am still unable to deploy it. I'm encountering the same issue. However, yesterday I created another account with a different card and email, and it has the same configurations, but it is working fine. However, the old one is still facing the same issue

Check your permissions.
